# mysql: exporting table to xml without concrete column

Tags: xml, mysql

To export data from a certain mysql table to xml I use the following command:

```
mysqldump --xml -t -u [username] --password=[password] [database] [table] > /path/to/file.xml
```

and it works just fine.
My problem is that it exports all columns from the table and I do not want this. I need the xml output for unit testing, so having a column "created_at" in the output would make all of my tests fail.

So my question is: assuming I have a mysql table called "Table", with columns "col_1, created, col_2", how can I mark "created" as column that will NOT be shown in the output xml file obtained via `mysqldump` command?

UPDATE: I cannot answer my question now, I will do it later. I needed it for PHPUnit, but actually instead of filtering mysqldump output, I can filter DataSet directly in PHPUnit.

```
  $filterDataSet = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_DataSetFilter($notFilteredDataSet);
  $filterDataSet->setExcludeColumnsForTable('Table', array('created_at'));
```

will do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can control which records get dumped by adding a `WHERE` clause to your mysqldump command (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where).

Comment: that's indeed nice! what I need however is to control columns

Comment: I misunderstood - thanks for clarifying. I would drop the column after importing the dump file: alter table drop column created_at. Then run your tests.